# import cython code in python

Tags: python, gcc, makefile, cython, gnu-make

I have an Cython code "**rotate_polygon_nms.pyx**" and I tried to import it in python code but it gives me an error:

The ***Cython*** code is::

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

assert sizeof(int) == sizeof(np.int32_t)

cdef extern from "rotate_gpu_nms.hpp":
    void _rotate_nms(np.int32_t*, int*, np.float32_t*, int, int, float, int)

def rotate_gpu_nms(np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] dets, np.float_t thresh, np.int32_t device_id=0):
    cdef int boxes_num = dets.shape[0]
    cdef int boxes_dim = dets.shape[1]
    cdef int num_out
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] \
        keep = np.zeros(boxes_num, dtype=np.int32)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=1] \
        scores = dets[:, 5]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] \
        order = scores.argsort()[::-1]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float32_t, ndim=2] \
        sorted_dets = dets[order, :]
    thresh = <np.float>thresh
    _rotate_nms(&keep[0], &num_out, &sorted_dets[0, 0], boxes_num, boxes_dim, thresh, device_id)
    keep = keep[:num_out]
    return order[keep]
```

The ***rotate_gpu_nms.hpp*** code is::

```
void _rotate_nms(int* keep_out, int* num_out, const float* boxes_host, int boxes_num,
          int boxes_dim, float nms_overlap_thresh, int device_id);
```

The error is

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "inference1.py", line 17, in
>   
>       from libs.fast_rcnn import build_fast_rcnn1   File "../libs/fast_rcnn/build_fast_rcnn1.py", line 14, in 
>       from libs.box_utils import nms_rotate   File "../libs/box_utils/nms_rotate.py", line 13, in 
>       from libs.box_utils.rotate_polygon_nms import rotate_gpu_nms ImportError: No module named 'libs.box_utils.rotate_polygon_nms'

I tried to use the two command bellow but it gives me an error too.

```
import pyximport 
pyximport.install()
```

The error::

> In file included from /usr/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:0,
>                    from /usr/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
>                    from /usr/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
>                    from /home/ashwaq/.pyxbld/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyrex/libs/box_utils/rotate_polygon_nms.c:525:
>   /usr/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning
>   "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining
>   NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]  #warning "Using
>   deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \   ^~~~~~~
>   /home/ashwaq/.pyxbld/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/pyrex/libs/box_utils/rotate_polygon_nms.c:527:10:
>   fatal error: rotate_gpu_nms.hpp: No such file or directory  #include
>   "rotate_gpu_nms.hpp"
>             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py",
>   line 118, in _compile
>       extra_postargs)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line
>   909, in spawn
>       spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 36, in
>   spawn
>       _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/spawn.py", line 159,
>   in _spawn_posix
>       % (cmd, exit_status)) distutils.errors.DistutilsExecError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py",
>   line 215, in load_module
>       inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py",
>   line 191, in build_module
>       reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyximport/pyxbuild.py",
>   line 102, in pyx_to_dll
>       dist.run_commands()   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in
>   run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in
>   run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py",
>   line 185, in run
>       _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py",
>   line 339, in run
>       self.build_extensions()   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py",
>   line 193, in build_extensions
>       self.build_extension(ext)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py",
>   line 533, in build_extension
>       depends=ext.depends)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line
>   574, in compile
>       self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)   File
>   "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py",
>   line 120, in _compile
>       raise CompileError(msg) distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "inference1.py", line 17, in
>   
>       from libs.fast_rcnn import build_fast_rcnn1   File "../libs/fast_rcnn/build_fast_rcnn1.py", line 14, in 
>       from libs.box_utils import nms_rotate   File "../libs/box_utils/nms_rotate.py", line 13, in 
>       from libs.box_utils.rotate_polygon_nms import rotate_gpu_nms   File
>   "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py",
>   line 458, in load_module
>       language_level=self.language_level)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py",
>   line 231, in load_module
>       raise exc.with_traceback(tb)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py",
>   line 215, in load_module
>       inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyximport/pyximport.py",
>   line 191, in build_module
>       reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyximport/pyxbuild.py",
>   line 102, in pyx_to_dll
>       dist.run_commands()   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in
>   run_commands
>       self.run_command(cmd)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in
>   run_command
>       cmd_obj.run()   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py",
>   line 185, in run
>       _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py",
>   line 339, in run
>       self.build_extensions()   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py",
>   line 193, in build_extensions
>       self.build_extension(ext)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/command/build_ext.py",
>   line 533, in build_extension
>       depends=ext.depends)   File "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/ccompiler.py", line
>   574, in compile
>       self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)   File
>   "/home/ashwaq/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/distutils/unixccompiler.py",
>   line 120, in _compile
>       raise CompileError(msg) ImportError: Building module libs.box_utils.rotate_polygon_nms failed:
>   ["distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status
>   1\n"]

how can I solve this problem??
I use python in Ubuntu

This is the [code](https://github.com/yangxue0827/R2CNN_FPN_Tensorflow) that I used

EDIT::
I used the distutils as @DavidW mension but when I did the command bellow, it gives me error::

```
setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

> Compiling rotate_polygon_nms.pyx because it changed. [1/1] Cythonizing
>   rotate_polygon_nms.pyx
>
> Error compiling Cython file:
>
> ### ------------------------------------------------------------ ... import numpy as np ^
>
> rotate_polygon_nms.pyx:1:0:
>   'R2CNN_FPN_Tensorflow-master.libs.box_utils.rotate_polygon_nms' is not
>   a valid module name Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "setup.py", line 6, in 
>       ext_modules = cythonize("rotate_polygon_nms.pyx"),   File "/home/ashwaq/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py",
>   line 1039, in cythonize
>       cythonize_one(*args)   File "/home/ashwaq/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py",
>   line 1161, in cythonize_one
>       raise CompileError(None, pyx_file) Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: rotate_polygon_nms.pyx

Comment: 1) You're probably better [using distutils](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html#building-a-cython-module-using-distutils) rather than pyx import for anything except the simplest modules. 2) The error you report isn't the complete error message and _definitely isn't_ the useful part.

Comment: I tried to use the using distutils but it also gives me this error >raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: rotate_polygon_nms.pyx

Comment: If you're getting that kind of error then it's probably happening in both distutils and pyximport

Comment: Show us how you are running `cython` on the `pyx` file, and how you are compiling the resulting `c` code.  You can't import `pyx` file directly into a Python session.

Comment: I can't reproduce your CompileError based on what you've given... again, more details (with full error messages) would be useful

Comment: I updated the question, please can you check it again

Comment: Right... with distutils it's ended up reading your file path and decided that `R2CNN_FPN_Tensorflow-master` should be included in the module name (the problem is the `-`). I'm never 100% sure how to fix it, but that's what you should be trying to avoid. For pyximport it isn't finding `rotate_gpu_nms.hpp`. You might need to set an include directory